# AndroidX native library support in codenameone

Tags: codenameone, androidx

We have a third party native SDK that is done in AndroidX, to which extent we can use it in codenameone, and what is the roadmap of AndroidX integration codenamone.

Many thanks for your prompt response, we have some decisions to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the task for [AndroidX support](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2948) to the 7.0 timeframe. Initially we hoped to get 7.0 out the door much sooner but since it was delayed it makes sense to do that task now.

Some developers were able to get AndroidX libraries working with some creative build hints but I can't find their posts at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot Shai,

We also have been able to get it work but by modifying the config of the Android studio project.

Can you confirm, the other developpers did on the CN1 build hint ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Steve answered that in a comment on the issue linked in my answer